# pyenv error while installing virtualenvwrapper

Tags: python, virtualenv

I am having issues installing source virtualenvwrapper.sh I am following the instruction [here](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). I have py 3.6.8 installed using pyenv.

```
source /home/joel/.pyenv/shims/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

It breaks the server connection and gives following output

```
pyenv: -bash: command not found
Connection to 199.168.0.37 closed.
```

my .bashrc config file

```
## pyenv configs
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/.virtualenvs
export PYENV_ROOT="$HOME/.pyenv"
export PATH="$PYENV_ROOT/bin:$PATH"

if command -v pyenv 1>/dev/null 2>&1; then
  eval "$(pyenv init -)"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what the script that works fine on my computer:

```
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python3 # tell which python is to be used
export WORKON_HOME=/root/.pyenv/  # tell where the python virtual environment files are
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh    # execute 'virtualenvwrapper.sh'
```